# Cannot resolve symbol 'osmdroid' when importing (import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory; & import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;)

Tags: android, mobile, osmdroid

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to use OSM for my app and I can't find any solution to this. I followed every step of this site https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library.html but I got stuck with that error. I don't understand why it doesn't import. Hoping someone can help. Thanks

Comment: The page you have linked is step two. First you have to include osmdroid into your project which is mentioned in the first sentence: [HowToGradle](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/How-to-add-the-osmdroid-library-via-Gradle)

Comment: @Robert the gradle thingy step said, for example - **implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:(INSERT_VERSION_HERE)'**

I did -
**implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:(6.1.13)'**

I just found out I have to remove the ()

Fixed it by changing it to:
**implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.13'**
Thank you for making me look at the gradle again.